How do I determine the constructor bytecode for contracts created by another contract
I am looking to decode constructor arguments for EVM contracts. Some contracts are created by externally owned accounts, but many are created via a contract transaction.
In both cases how can I reliably determine the constructor bytecode so that I can decode the constructor arguments?
I have the creation bytecode from the trace where the contract was created, and I have the constructor abi. I also know that the last x bytes of the creation bytecode contain the constructor args, but how do I know how many bytes I should fetch (given that some types are dynamic in size).
The code snippet below explains what I'm trying to do.
from eth_abi import abi
from web3 import Web3 

creation_bytecode = "0x...."
constructor_args_size ="???"
constructor_types = ["address", "bytes"]

creation_bytecode_args = creation_bytecode[-constructor_args_size:]
bytes_encoded = Web3.to_bytes(hexstr=creation_bytecode_args)
decoded_args = abi.decode(constructor_types, bytes_encoded)

# expect something like ["0x95222290DD7278Aa3Ddd389Cc1E1d165CC4BAfe5", "b',\xbe\x0c\xb9\xad\x9a\x94Uv\xa5\xbbS'"]

Things I have tried

I have tried variations of comparing the deployed bytecode to the creation bytecode to determine which bytes are for the constructor arguments, but this does not work reliably

